# Implications of martingale property

Tags: probability, martingale

Consider the sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2, X_3,\dots$. Suppose this sequence is a martingale, that is
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(1) \quad E(|X_t|)<\infty\\
&(2) \quad E(X_t| \mathcal{F}_{t-1})=X_{t-1},
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}\equiv \sigma(X_1,\dots, X_{t-1})$.
Does this imply that
$$
(*) \quad X_t=X_{t-1}+U_{t-1} \quad \text{s.t. }\quad E(U_{t-1}| \mathcal{F}_{t-1})=0\quad?
$$
Or, do I need further conditions to write $(*)$, such as finite second moments?

Comment: Well, you do need $\mathbb{E}(|U_{t-1}|)< \infty$, but other than that, you're good.

Comment: Why do you need $E(|U_{t-1}|)<\infty$ to write $(*)$? Could you show that in an answer?

Comment: Without that, how do you know that $\mathbb{E}(|X_t|) < \infty$?

Comment: (1) and (2) are assumptions. I would say that (1) IMPLIES $E(|U_{t-1}|)<\infty$.

Comment: *Define* $U_{t-1} = X_t - X_{t-1}$ and compute its conditional expectation.

Comment: @whuber Can you add more details? I think I'm confused on what is an implication and what is a definition. Am I doing something wrong in my question?

Comment: All you need is to apply the assumptions and to know the "taking out what is known" property of conditional expectation.

Comment: If I do so, $$E(U_{t-1}|\mathcal{F}_{t-1})=E(X_{t}| \mathcal{F}_{t-1})- E(X_{t-1}|\mathcal{F}_{t-1})=X_{t-1}-X_{t-1}=0.$$ This is the condition on $U_{t-1}$ that I wrote. I infer from your answer that I do not need anything else to write $(*)$. Correct?

Comment: @TEX Correct.  But I am wondering, is there any particular reason to use $U_{t - 1}$ instead of $U_t$?